# Question about the formal definition of limits

Tags: limits, definition

[Here](https://youtu.be/0sCttufU-jQ) Salman Khan discusses about the formal definition of limits. He tries to prove that a function $f(x)$ has a limit $L$ if $x$ approaches $c$ by expressing $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$. In other words, if $\epsilon$ is given, if we can find the value of $\delta$ so that all the $x$ values that satisfy $|x-c|<\delta$, also satisfy $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, the limit exists.

**My questions:**

1. Is my description of the formal definition of limits correct?
2. Can we go the other way around? I mean that if we are given $\delta$, if we can find the value of $\epsilon$ so that all $x$ values that satisfy $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, also satisfy $|x-c|<\delta$, can we say that the limit exists?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yep, my bad; I edited it.

Comment: 2 is wrong. However, if you modify it to this, "if we are given $\delta$, if we can find the value of $\epsilon$ so that all $x$ values in this range $c-\delta<x<c+\delta$ that satisfy $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, also satisfy $|x-c|<\delta$, can we say that the limit exists?", then you can see this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192985/768162)

Comment: A better definition of limit can be written in this way: Let $f(x)$ is a real function that is defined for all values near $a$. We can say the limit exists, that is $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$, if for every positive $\epsilon$ a corresponding positive $\delta$ is found such that whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No, that will not work. Suppose, say, that $f$ is the sine function, and that $c=0$. Then $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)=0$ (by the usual definition). But, given $\delta>0$, there is no $\varepsilon>0$ such that, whenever $|\sin(x)|<\varepsilon$, you have $|x|<\delta$, since $\sin(n\pi)=0$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: What a brilliant answer; thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty understand your explanation of 2. Instead of the sine function, would it be possible for you to explain it using the straight-line $f(x)=x$ with this $\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)=2$.

Comment: No, I cannot, because that function has limit $2$ at the point $2$ *and* your property holds.

Comment: What0s the problem with my example? For *any* $\delta>$, there are points $x$ of the form $n\pi$ ($n\in\Bbb Z$) with $|x|\geqslant\delta$. So, it is *not true that, when $\sin(x)-0|<\varepsilon$, then $|x|<\delta$.

Comment: It'd be of great help to me if you show me an example: if $c=0$, $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x)=0$ and $\delta=0.5$, could you please show me kind sir how $|x|>\delta$?

Comment: Sure. Take $x=\pi$. Then $|\sin(x)-0|<\varepsilon$ (whatever $\varepsilon>0$ is), but $|x|=\pi>\delta$.

Comment: If $\delta=0.5$ and $c=0$, shouldn't $x$ be between $0-0.5<x<0+0.5$? If yes, how can we take $x=\pi$ when $\pi$ doesn't fall within the aforementioned range?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130125/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-tryingtobeastoic).